# How to use edit text as search box in expandable listview android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my application i am using expandable list view.Now i want to use search box for display the filtered expandable list view  items.For this purpose i am using the following code

```
    search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
    search.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    search.setOnCloseListener(this);
```

But this coding only supports above API 11.But i want to implement these feature in below API 11.

This is the way of using edit text as search view for the default list view adapter

```
  inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please give me suggestions for how to use edit text for searching in  custom expandable list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i did is, why implemented a search for my Data myself.

i added a TextView to the Actionbar and i handle the input in my ListAdapter.

as you are targeting api below 11 you will either have to add ActionBarSherlock, or place the TextView elsewhere.

```
    EditText tv = new EditText(this);
    tv.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                yourAdapter.filterData(v.getText());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

this is how i would design a textView to handle a search. you will have to implement the search yourself, because my data is backed by an sqlite database so i just hand off the search to the sql database.

```
public void filterData(String query){

  query = query.toLowerCase();
  Log.v("MyListAdapter", String.valueOf(continentList.size()));
  continentList.clear();

  if(query.isEmpty()){
   continentList.addAll(originalList);
  }
  else {

   for(Continent continent: originalList){

    ArrayList<Country> countryList = continent.getCountryList();
    ArrayList<Country> newList = new ArrayList<Country>();
    for(Country country: countryList){
     if(country.getCode().toLowerCase().contains(query) ||
       country.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)){
      newList.add(country);
     }
    }
    if(newList.size() > 0){
     Continent nContinent = new Continent(continent.getName(),newList);
     continentList.add(nContinent);
    }
   }
  }

  Log.v("MyListAdapter", String.valueOf(continentList.size()));
  notifyDataSetChanged();

 }
```

you would have to update the search method to fit your data.

Comment: added some sample code of a TextView you could use as a SearchView.

Comment: No.this is not my solution.Because i am using custom expandable list view adapter.

Comment: yeah and you would have to search the data in your adapter. Your problem is that you wont be able to use SearchView in api 11 and lower. so you need to use something else. for example the TextView, which i just noticed is supposed to be an EditText =D
And you need to add a Method that is able to search in your data.

Comment: Yeah you could do that as well. The only difference is that my method does no livesearch. i wait for the user to press enter to start the search. You are searching every time the user changes his input.

Comment: Yes..But my posted codings are not worked for my custom expandable list view

Comment: my guess is that the way you apply the filter doesnt work for an expandableListView. but here is an example of how to search in an expandble ListView http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-expandablelistview-search.html

Comment: Yes i refer that.But it only applicable for API 11

Comment: yes, you are not supposed to use it. you are just supposed to use their search method. thats just basic java to search in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use actionBarCompat for backward compatibility.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Comment: Try to use SearchViewCompat.